# If $F(x(z),z)=0$ and $F(x_0,0)=0$ is there a sequence $x(z)$ that converges to $x_0$ as $z$ converges to zero?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a function $F: \mathbb{R}^{N+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$, let $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $z \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $x(z)$ be defined implicitly by $F(x(z),z)=0$. (Here $x(z)$ could be a correspondence if there are multiple solutions in $x$ to $F(x,z) = 0$.) Let $x_0$ be such that $F(x_0,0)=0$. What are conditions on $F$ such that there is a sequence $x(z)$ that converges to $x_0$ as $z \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: It would seem that the condition should simply be continuity of $F(x,z)$ at $(x_0,0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, continuity, even uniform, isn't sufficient. Without loss of generality, let's choose $x_0=0$, and consider the function :
$$
F(x,z) := (xz-1) (x^2+z^2)\, e^{-(x^2+z^2)}.
$$
[Here is a rescaled visualization.](https://www.math3d.org/PEagH2TKA)

The polynomial part implies that the only roots of $F$ are $(x,z)=(\frac{1}{z},z)$ when $z\neq0$, and $(x,z)=(0,0)$, meaning $x(z)$ is uniquely defined for every $z\in\mathbb{R}$ as :
$$
x(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{z} &\text{if } z\neq 0, \\
0 &\text{if } z=0,
\end{cases}
$$
and so there is no way for $x(z)$ to converge to $0$ as $z\to0$.

Moreover, the exponential ensures that $F$ is uniformly continuous and well-behaved altogether.

You would need $F$ to explicitly always have roots in any neighborhood of $(x_0,0)$, which is basically just a rewording of what you're trying to find ("there is a sequence $x(z)$ that converges to $x_0$ as $z\to0$").

$ $

**EDIT:**
Here is a result that can be applied to the function you gave, $F(x,z) = \frac{x}{x^{-\varepsilon}+1} - \frac{x^{-\varepsilon}}{zx^{-\varepsilon}+1}$. It's maybe not as simple as you'd hope, but I think it's still pretty general.

**Theorem.**
*Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$. Suppose there exist $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1<x_2$ and:*
\begin{align*}
(x,z)\mapsto\, &F(x,z) \text{ is continuous over } [x_1,x_2]\times I, \\
\forall z\in I: x\mapsto\, &F(x,z) \text{ is strictly monotone over } [x_1,x_2], \\
\forall z\in I:\, &F(x_1,z) \leq 0 \leq F(x_2,z).
\end{align*}
*Then for every $z\in I$, there exists a unique $x(z)\in[x_1,x_2]$ such that $F(x(z),z)=0$. Moreover, $z\mapsto x(z)$ is continuous.*

This is just an application of the intermediate value theorem, with some extra legwork to prove the continuity of $x(z)$. I'm sure we could relax the hypotheses to have moving bounds, non-strict monotonicity, and even no monotonicity at all, but this is sufficient for our purposes.

**Proof:** Using the continuity and the fact that $F(x_1,z)\leq 0 \leq F(x_2,z)$, we directly have by the intermediate value theorem the existence of an $x(z)\in[x_1,x_2]$ such that $F(x(z),z)=0$ for every $z\in I$. And since $x\mapsto F(x,z)$ is strictly monotone, this $x(z)$ is unique for every $z\in I$.

Let's prove the continuity by contradiction. Suppose there's a discontinuity at some $z^*\in I$. That means we can find an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(z_n)_n$ in $I$ such that $z_n\to z^*$ and $|x(z^*)-x(z_n)|>\epsilon$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Since $(x(z_n))_n$ is bounded in $[x_1,x_2]$, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, there exists a convergent subsequence $(x(z_{n_k}))_k$. Let's call its limit $x^*$. Since $[x_1,x_2]$ is closed, necessarily $x^*\in[x_1,x_2]$. Also, $|x(z^*)-x^*|\geq\epsilon \Rightarrow x^*\neq x(z^*)$.

By the continuity of $F$, we have $F(x^*,z^*)=0$. Yet we also have $F(x(z^*),z^*)=0$ and $x^*\neq x(z^*)$. This contradicts the strict monotonicity of $x\mapsto F(x,z)$, and so $z\mapsto x(z)$ has to be continuous. $\square$

$ $

Now, we just need to apply our theorem to your $F$ :
$$
F(x,z) = \frac{x}{x^{-\varepsilon}+1} - \frac{x^{-\varepsilon}}{zx^{-\varepsilon}+1}.
$$
Just graphing a function can drive a lot of the intuition behind proving something, so try and experiment a bit and see what patterns you can find visually. [Here's a Desmos graph of $x\mapsto F(x,z)$ for some $z$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/atsps8pkar).

Since we want to study $F$ as $z$ approaches $0$, for now, let's choose $I=[0,1]$. We need to find $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x_1,z)\leq 0\leq F(x_2,z)$ for every $z\in[0,1]$.

Looking at $F$, we can see it increases with $z$ for some fixed $x$. Since $\lim_{x\to0^+} F(x,1) = -1$, we can just choose $x_1>0$ small enough so that $F(x_1,1)\leq 0$, and so $F(x_1,z)\leq 0$ for every $z\in[0,1]$.

Similarly, since $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x,0) = +\infty$, we can choose $x_2$ large enough so that $F(x_2,0)\geq0$. Because $z\mapsto F(x_2,z)$ is increasing, we have $F(x_2,z)\geq0$ for every $z\in[0,1]$.

We now have $0<x_1<x_2$ such that $F(x_1,z)\leq 0\leq F(x_2,0)$, and we can also see that $F$ is continuous over $[x_1,x_2]\times[0,1]$. Let's prove that $x\mapsto F(x,z)$ is a strictly increasing function.

Fixing $z\in[0,1]$ and differentiating with respect to $x$, we have :
\begin{align*}
\partial_x F(x,z)
&= \frac{1}{x^{-\varepsilon}+1} + \frac{\varepsilon x^{-\varepsilon}}{(x^{-\varepsilon}+1)^2} + \frac{\varepsilon x^{-\varepsilon-1}}{zx^{-\varepsilon}+1} - \frac{2\varepsilon z x^{-2\varepsilon-1}}{(zx^{-\varepsilon}+1)^2} \\
&\geq \frac{1}{x_2^{-\varepsilon}+1} - z\frac{2\varepsilon x_2^{-2\varepsilon-1}}{(zx_2^{-\varepsilon}+1)^2}.
\end{align*}
Since the right-hand side of that inequality converges to $\frac{1}{x_2^{-\varepsilon}+1}>0$ as $z\to0$, we can choose $\bar{z}\in(0,1]$ small enough so that $\partial_x F(x,z)>0$ for all $(x,z)\in [x_1,x_2]\times[0,\bar{z}]$, and so $x\mapsto F(x,z)$ is strictly increasing.

Everything else we've proven stays true if we replace $[0,1]$ by $[0,\bar{z}]$, so choosing $I=[0,\bar{z}]$, we can apply our theorem to get the existence of a unique and continuous map $z\mapsto x(z)$ such that $F(x(z),z)=0$. Since $z\mapsto x(z)$ is continuous over $[0,\bar{z}]$, we get $\lim_{z\to 0} x(z) = x(0)$, which is exactly what we wanted!

$ $

So you see, this is not something that's trivial to prove. Not to mention that this works when $x$ is in one dimension, and it could also be generalized if $F$ was of the form $F:\mathbb{R}^{N+1}\to \mathbb{R}$, but the arguments break down when it's of the form $F:\mathbb{R}^{N+1}\to \mathbb{R}^N$, since we can't apply the intermediate value theorem so straightforwardly.

Comment: I think you missed a minus sign in the roots of F

Comment: Oops you're right, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this. I wonder if differentiability of $F(x,z)$ at $(x_0,0)$ would ensure the result.

Comment: This $F$ is actually infinitely differentiable everywhere (with bounded and uniformly continuous derivatives). Also I chose this $F$ so that $x(z)$ could at least be defined for every $z$, but notice that there are many functions for which it's not, e.g. $F(x,z)=x^2+z^2$ only has one root at $(0,0)$ and so $x(z)$ is undefined for every $z\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. The problem is that I don't have the solution $x(z)$ to show that for $z$ close enough to zero $x(z)$ is close enough to $x_0$. This is because I don't have the explicit solution $x(z)$. Is there something I can do directly on $F(x,z)$?

Comment: That all depends on your $F$. Depending on what it looks like, it might be possible to show that there are roots close to $(x_0,0)$ without necessarily knowing the exact value of $x(z)$. But in regards to your question, I can't think of any simple test you could do to know if a general function would have that property.

Comment: This is a much sumplified version of what I actually have, but it captures the key issue. The function is $$F(x,z)=\frac{1}{x^{-\varepsilon}+1}x-\frac{x^{-\varepsilon}}{zx^{-\varepsilon}+1}.$$ It seems obvious that $x\left(n\right)\rightarrow x_{0}$ with $x_{0}$ defined implicitly by $$\frac{1}{x_{0}^{-\varepsilon}+1}x_{0}=x_{0}^{-\varepsilon}.$$ But what is the right / formal way of approaching this?

Comment: I guess the key is that in that equation for $x_0$ there is a unique, positive and finite $x_0$ and hence one can take the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}F(x,z)$.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the continuity of $F(x,z)$ with the continuity of $x(z)$. Even if $x_0$ is unique, positive, and finite, and even if we find a sequence $(x_n,z_n)$ such that $F(x_n,z_n) \to F(x_0,0)=0$, nothing guarantees that this is a sequence of **roots**, i.e. we can't say that $x_n=x(z_n)$ and $F(x_n,z_n)=0$. I've edited my answer to include a general condition I found to get what you're looking for, and applied it to the $F$ you gave.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would an alternative approach be to apply the implicit function theorem? If the Jacobian $F_x$ evaluated at $x_0$ is invertible then there is a function $x(z)$ defined for $z$ in an open set around $0$ satisfying $x(0) = x_0$. Right?

Comment: That's true actually, the implicit function theorem is very relevant here, the only issue in this specific case is that you would need to be able to evaluate $F_x$ at $x_0$, which may be difficult (though not impossible) if $x_0$ is itself defined implicitly.

Comment: I wonder now if we need the monotonicity assumption in the theorem. Once you apply the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and continuity of $F$ then we know there is a subsequence of $x(z)$ for $F(x(z),z)=0$ with $z \rightarrow 0$ such that $F(x(0),0)=0$, which is what I wanted. Even if there are multiple solutions to $F(x,0)=0$, we would know there is a sequence $x(z)$ that converges to one of them.